# Closure condition of spherical polygons

Tags: spherical-geometry

Given an open spherical polygon of geodesic edge length $L_i$ ($i=0,..,n$) and anterior spherical angles $A_i$ ($i=0,..,n-1$). My question is what are sufficient and nessecary conditions on the lengths of arcs $L_i$ and on $A_i$ for the closure of that polygon?

Comment: What have you tried?  What's an "open spherical polygon"?

Comment: I mean by open spherical polygon a sequence of points P_i  (i=0,..,n) on S^2  with P_0 is different to P_n. What i m looking for is conditions on Lengths and angles (spherical) that guanties P_0=P_n .

Comment: Anterior is supplement to interior angle?

Comment: Are points P_i in a plane? Anterior is supplement to interior angle?

Comment: So what is the difference between and "open" and a "closed" spherical polygon?